# trouble in loading web page in ASP.Net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

In ASP.Net C# (Visual Studio), In my localhost, while debugger(breakpoints) started, if i click on a submit button then values are submitted into the database.

But when I remove the debugger(breakpoints) and hit the submit button it shows error "Check your internet connection" in internet explorer and the values are not submitted to the database.

How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: You're going to have to clarify a bit. It seems like you're using a local server to host your web site / application that only runs when you have the debugger on, so when it's off, the development server is down. Are you running IIS on your machine?

Comment: @BrDaHa: the statement `only runs when you have the debugger on` in your comment is wrong , OP can also run his aaplication without debugger by presing `Ctrl+F5` .

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi nope, ctrl+f5 still launches a development server, but doesn't attach the debugger. Both pressing f5 or ctrl+f5 will launch the development server (given he has the properties set that way), so the web app will run. As soon as you press the stop button, the dev server goes down. If you want to run it without the dev server, then you have to publish the application somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from `Visual Studio` you can run your application because default Test Webserver will be started by VS when you run in debug mode.

so when you stop the Debugger from `Visual Studio` automatically VS stops the webserver hence your application is failing to run.to solve the problem you can either `host` your `webapplication` on `IIS` server or if you want to still run the Apllication on local machine with `visual studio` without debugger enabled try this

in Visual Studio `MENU` bar ->Goto `Debug-> Start Without Debugging`
 or
simply press shortcut keys `Ctrl+F5`

Comment: did you start your application by pressing `Ctrl+F5`? which error ur getting?

Comment: yes,but still same error when i removes breakpoints in application

Comment: then error is some where not related to breakpoints, could you please post your code?

Answer (score 0):

When you run the web page from visual studio it started the web server after that it run your web page but if you don't start the server and try to open the web pages it will get error. You can use this link for how to start the server without the visual studio .
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58wxa9w5.aspx
Thank You.

Comment: Actually i have started the server